# Save button not responding- why DOM is null after I fill out data on UI

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Now I have a save button that's not working. When I click on it nothing happens on UI.

```
<img src="/something/image/Save.jpg" border="0" style="cursor:hand" alt="Save" 
onclick="if(validate_edit()){pop_comment('edit');}"> 


function pop_comment(src)
{
 //document.all.comment.value=document.getElementsByTagName('comment');
 window.showModalDialog("./jsp/util/comment.jsp?src="+src, window, "dialogHeight=320px; dialogWidth=500px; dialogLeft=100px; dialogTop=150px; resizable=yes; status=no;scroll=no;");
}
```

After I click on Save button I see below error on console:

```
violator_edit.do:354 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at validate_edit (edit.do:354)
    at HTMLImageElement.onclick (edit.do:1035)
```

and says this line in validate_edit() caused the error:

```
var state = document.getElementById('wsbean.state').value;
```

I wrote this test:

```
if(document.getElementById('wsbean.state')==null)(console.log("null"))

Result: 
null
```

So the DOM object is not ready. But why? I did fill out state on UI. 
Could it be because of the script tag position? the HTML of the page looks like this:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <Script></Script>
    <div></div>--> the whole form is inside this div
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So no errors in the console? Is `validate_edit()` returning true?

Comment: Also showModalDialog only works in some older browsers.

Comment: Looks like you need to do some debugging and then update your question with the results of that debugging.

Comment: add validate_edit() function code

Comment: the problem is when the browser wants to run validate_edit() it tries to get the value of something which is null just like null.value

Comment: I now got that the DOM object is null. Now how do I find out why it's null?